# Trying to create more than the maximum possible number of threads in a Windows 32-Bit system

Tags: windows, multithreading, operating-system

What happens when I then try to create another thread (after reaching the maximum amount of threads?)

Comment: for what you need create so many threads ?

Comment: I don't! I'm learning for my finals and I had to calculate the maximum number of threads on the described system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreateThread` will fail when you run out of resources.

`ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY` in a normal configuration and `ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES` with small stack reserve.

See [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Processes and Threads](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/07/05/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/) for more details.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your fast and precise answer!